# Pinging a server to check if it is up or not

Tags: php

Im working with return statement, to see how it work I have created scrip where to ping ip address and get the result back with return statement but doesn’t work please see my code and let me know where I have gone wrong.

Thanks

```
function ping () {
    $sun = exec ("ping -c 3  192.168.5.1",$output, $status );
    return $sun;
}

$pingc = ping();
echo "$pingc \n";

if ( $pingc == 0 ) {
    echo "host is up \n";
}
else {
    echo "host is down \n"; 
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What exactly happens?

Comment: when i ran the script it just give host is up even if the host is down.

Comment: You may reconsider changing the question title, as it seems that it's a problem with the return of a generic function, and not something referring only to `exec()`

Answer (score 3):

you can use *fsockopen* to test the availability of an address, example:

```
if (@fsockopen("192.168.5.1", 80)===false)
   echo 'host is down\n';
else
   echo 'host is up\n';
```

the second parameter is the port (80 here)

Comment: Ah, darn, that is a much cleaner way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the value from the `exec`-command incorrectly. If you read the [PHP-docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), it clearly states that the output itself it stored in the variable assigned as the second argument.

I tried to simply dump the content of `$output` and the result I got was:

```
Array
(
    [0] => PING 192.168.5.1 (192.168.5.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
    [1] => 
    [2] => --- 192.168.5.1 ping statistics ---
    [3] => 3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms
    [4] => 
)
```

EDIT: As Marcelo Pascual pointed out, the last line is returned from the `exec`-command. In this case it is the empty line `\n`, which is (obviously) not true or false. You will have to take the array and check the information if the ping was successful or not.

So, here's a simple code that should be able to determine if the server is offline or online.

```
function ping() {
    exec ("ping -c 3  192.168.5.1", $output);

    $status = true;
    foreach ($output as $v) {
        if (strpos($v, '100% packet loss') !== false) {
            $status = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $status;
}

if (ping())
    // Server is up
else
    // Server is down
```

Comment: `exec()` returns the last line of the output.

Comment: @MarceloPascual: Ah, thank you, I'll edit my answer. I was not aware of that, but it makes sense now.

Comment: Im confused here about return can you please spare with me minutes and explain why you used return here.

Comment: @hadi What about the return? You are calling the method and using an if to check if the server is up or not. The return-statement will return true (1) if the server is up and false (0) if the server is down. It is sat to true before it checks if there was a 100% packet loss. If there was a 100% packet loss, it will return false instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can't run `exec()` on your system, or the command is wrong. 
If you want to test the return functionality, try something simpler:

```
<?php

function salute() {
    return 'Hello';
}

echo salute();

?>
```

You should do some debugging:

- To see if `exec()` is available in your system, simply try: `print_r( exec('YOUR_COMMAND_HERE') );`
- Check your error_log file
- Add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of your script.

Comment: I think OptimusCrime's answer is the correct one. In this case, `exec()` returns an empty string, which is the last line of executed command.